# IDE to upload code to LPC1343 over USB

Tags: lpc

LPC1343 when connected to PC acts like a mass storage device.How can I upload code to the microcontroller.Is there any IDE which converts the C program to .bin for uploading the code?If so,please tell me the IDE names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [LPCXpresso](https://www.lpcware.com/lpcxpresso) IDE from NXP. Once you compiled your code, you can drag the bin to LPC1343 mass storage device for flashing.
Check [this](http://www.nxp.com/documents/other/LPCXpresso_Getting_Started_User_Guide.pdf) manual too.

Comment: I am not using LPCXpresso.I am doing my own custom built board using LPC1343 with USB connectivity only.I saw in many websites that LPC1343 has builtin bootloader during manufacture.I completed my designing of the board.I think it'll work.What is your suggestion?Waiting for your valuable suggestion. :)

Comment: @Aadarsh take a look at the device manual http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10375.pdf chapter 21 . In the section 21.9 you can see that there is an USB ISP on this device. You can used to flash your target. Before copying your binary to the target you will need to insert the checksum on it as described in the section 21.9.1

Comment: I gone through the contents.Since I am beginner to 32 bit micro-controllers,I cant understand the term checksum,what is checksum.How can I insert a checksum in the micro-controller.Do I need any JTAG or some other debugger to do it?Please explain me about checksum and implementation the fresh LPC1343 micro-controller :)

Comment: I've found an application note from NXP that can help you http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10986.pdf

Comment: I got the point.Now I am preparing my board.A small doubt arises.Is it necessary to use USB soft connect? or manually working is okay?